# I would like to overlay 2 images on top of each other for registration matching, but

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, registration, matching

the part that gets complicated for me, is that i want one to be RGB and the other in grayscale. I've seen on this website that it can be done with OpenCV and the AddWeighted function. The problem is that it only works for 2 images of the same kind, and i would like to mix (color and grayscale). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your RGB image to grey, then do the matching:

```
Mat rgb_image, rgb_now_grey;
Mat grey_image;
grey_image = imgread("grey.png");
rgb_image = imread("colour.png");
cvtColor(rgb_image, rgb_now_grey, CV_RGB2GRAY);

// register_images(rgb_now_grey, grey_image);
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what i'm looking for. I want to overlay two images that will store their type so when i overlay them, i will see 2 half transparent images overlaying each other, one in color and the other in grayscale